# Giving users access to a web site in virtual server running on a laptop

Tags: sharepoint, service

im running a sharepoint services website on my laptop using a virtual server on the same laptop. i need to show other people (on external machines) the website in a development stage. i have sent them the same address i am using to open and ive given them their own log ons- they work on my machine.

the problem is that the site comes up with the IE cannot display the webpage even before they get to the log on stage. ive only been using sharepoint for a few days and dont really know my way around- can anyone help please

Comment: where would i find the IIS map?, ive been using it for 2 days

Comment: Really, this has nothing to do with sharepoint - If you want people to access your computer, you need a server. I agree with colin, the http://serverfault.com crowd can help you better.

Comment: Stuart is right, this is not SharePoint, this has to do with Virtual networking (which by default will make the virutal machine visible on your machine, but not outside it..)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the IIS to map your internal server outside.